# Dota 2 Faceless Void Tier

Tags: dota-2

I was looking through a [Dota 2 Competitive Hero Tier List - August 2012](http://esfiworld.com/news/dota-2-competitive-hero-tier-list-august-2012) and I found `Void` in the `Tier 4: Rarely banned or picked`. I thought it was one of the most overpowered heroes in the game. Was I wrong? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in Tier 4 doesn't mean that the hero is bad. Faceless Void is a true hard carry, probably the most or one of the most powerful carries late game. With the right items he can wipe out the complete enemy team, but he is really item-dependent and the current metagame in competitive matches is more oriented to mid game with continuous ganks and fast pushing.

Anyway in pubs where these strategies are more difficult to apply, he can still easily dominate.

Answer (score 2):

That list is 4 months old, which in Dota2 terms is a very significant length of time. At that time the metagame was very much about pushing and ganking in order to secure easy farm for a midgame carry and breach a T3. Since then, the has been an introduction of Naga and Magnus and nerfs to popular midgame carries like Lycan and Morphling. We've also seen the rise of teamfight heroes like Jakiro, Keeper of the Light, Nyx Assassin and Undying plus somewhat level dependent carries like Luna and Sven. The metagame has thus become much more teamfight oriented.

Void's ultimate is one of the best teamfight skills in the game, but he hits his stride much later than most carries. This is because his damage output doesn't scale with levels at all (the aforementioned Luna and Sven both do- drastically), and so he needs at least two big items, usually more, to have a real impact in most teamfights.

Faceless Void has started to be picked quite a bit recently in response to these carries, who he cripples with bashes (though Sven himself has started to fall out of the metagame). The hero has also seen quite a bit of use by Sylar from LGD in China's G-League. You can see information about recent Faceless Void games here: http://dota-academy.com/hero/22/

However, he's still definitely not top tier, because he can be shut down by a variety of heroes with relative ease (generally those who can disable him from a range and through BKB). The most common counters are Bane, Beastmaster, and Batrider. He's also weak in trilane vs. trilane scenarios and against strong pushing in general. Thus, he's usually picked up later in drafts when a team's composition has been mostly played out. Situationally, he can be excellent.